# Binding radio buttons to array of objects

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, radio-button

I have my view model:

```
function (dataservice, Person){
    var genders = ko.observableArray();
    var languages = ko.observableArray();
    var person = ko.observableArray();

    function activate(){
        dataservice.getGenders(genders);
        dataservice.getGenders(languages);
    }

    var vm = {
        genders: genders,
        languages: languages,
        person: person
    };
}

function Person(person){
    var firtstName = person.firtstName;
    var familyName = person.familyName;
    var genderId = person.genderId;
    var languageId = person.languageId;
}
```

It's simplified for clarity.

Then I have my `Genders' data from server, it looks like this:

```
[{
    $id: "1",
    GenderId: 2,
    GenderName: "Female",
    GenderDescription: "Female",
    GenderCode: "F"
}]
```

I also have `Languages` that looks like this:

```
[{
    "$id": "1",
    "LanguageId": 2,
    "LanguageName": "Afar",
    "LanguageDescription": "Afar",
    "LanguageCode": "aa"
}]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to bind the `genders` array from my view model as a data source and use `Person.GenderId` as the value to be updated, in a way such that the correct radio button is initially selected. This selection depended on `Person.GenderId`.

I did something similar with `Languages` using a drop down and that works just fine:

```html
<section data-bind="with: $root.personModel">
   <select id="language" 
           data-bind="options: $root.languages, 
                      optionsText: 'LanguageName', 
                      optionsValue: 'LanguageId',
                      value: LanguageId, 
                      optionsCaption: 'none'">
    </select>
</section>
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing with radio buttons, but I don't know how to make it work. Here's what I have:

```html
<section data-bind="with: $root.personModel">
   <!-- ko foreach: $root.genders -->
   <input type="radio" 
          name="genders" 
          data-bind="attr: {value: GenderId}, checked: GenderId" />
   <span data-bind="text: $data.GenderName"></span>
   <!-- /ko -->
</section>
```

If I understood things correctly, the `foreach` binding works like `with` and changes my context, so I can't reach `GenderId` from my exposed `Person`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<input type="radio" name="genders" data-bind="attr: {value: GenderId}, checked: GenderId" />
```

to

```
<input type="radio" name="genders" data-bind="attr: {value: GenderId}, checked: $parent.GenderId" />
```

as explained [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

$parent: This is the view model object in the parent context, the one immeditely outside the current context. In the root context, this is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me a direction and with slightly modificated code it works just fine. It needed: `checked: $parents[1].GenderId`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to utilize the `checkdValue` binding, see the lower part of [the "checked" documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html).

Your code didn't quite translate to a repro, but here's my version more or less in your scenario. Suppose this bit of code:

```
var Person = function(person) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(person.name);
    self.gender = ko.observable(person.gender);
};

var root = {
    genders: [{ $id: "1", GenderId: 1, GenderName: "Female"},
              { $id: "2", GenderId: 2, GenderName: "Male"}]
};

root.personModel = new Person({name: 'john', gender: root.genders[1]});

ko.applyBindings(root);
```

Alongside this markup:

```html
<section data-bind="with: $root.personModel">
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.genders -->
    <input type="radio" 
           name="genders" 
           data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.personModel.gender" />
    <span data-bind="text: $data.GenderName"></span><br />
    <!-- /ko -->
</section>
```

This should work, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Bq36/1/).

The objects from the `genders` array are bound to the `checkedValue` of each `input`, and the personModel's gender is bound to `checked`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Main idea was to use `Id` property in model, and not the whole object. And for binding just reference this object from vm

Comment: Okay, np, I see someone else had a suggestion for that case as well. Leaving my answer up here just in case others landing here may want this approach.